# How do you add a method to the Django admin documentation for the model?

Tags: django, django-admin

The Django admin docs are great for designers trying to layout a page, you get all the model fields and quite a few of the inject related stuff as well  (get_status_display, title_set,....)

How can you add a method to that list in the admin docs so the designer can know about it?  An example would be something like get_full_name for a user, but another might be a method that tallies all of the hours in a list of jobs connected to a task.

I don't seem to find anything in the docs for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the admindoc page of the Django Documentation, it shows that you just have to use a tripple quote comment within the method and it will put it on up there!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/

Comment: Really don't know why I couldn't find that with google.  Must have been an off day.